# Xcode "You cannot run your app on a device" - validade archive

Tags: xcode, validation

Im having problem to validate the archive to submit to apple store.
When i click 'Validate...' (Organizer), show this message "You cannot run your app on a device".
I already tested my app on a device, but when i archive to validate appear this message.
I don't know what to do, i need help. 
Im using xcode 6.3.1, sdk 8.3.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I dont know why, but i have to go to xcode > preferences > accounts, and remove all accounts and put again. It's work for me.